# Python import: rosrun works well but roslaunch reports error

Tags: python, roslaunch, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm writing some rospy nodes recently and some import errors ocur when I utilize roslaunch to start my node.

```
a.py
1 import sys
2 sys.path.append("..")
3 from middle_abstraction.function_unit import FunctionUnit
```

ImportError: No module named middle_abstraction.function_unit

The file is organized as following

```
package
    scripts
       basic_support
          a.py
      middle_abstraction
          function_unit.py
```

When I `cd` to basic_support and run `python a.py`, everthing is working well as well as when I utilize `rosrun pkg a.py`. But when I utilize roslaunch, this error ocurs.

I have written one setup.py file in my pkg folder:

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['multi_robot_patrol'],#my pkg name
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    requires=['std_msgs', 'rospy', 'message_filters', 'gps_common', 'sensor_msgs']
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

I'm really confused that rosrun works pretty well but roslaunch reports import error. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230592/python-import:-rosrun-works-well-but-roslaunch-reports-error/) by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2016-03-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2016-03-30**:
In your setup.py you list 'src' as the package_dir but I don't see any 'src' directory in your package directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to change the **package_dir** in `setup.py` from "**src**" to "**scripts**". And **packages** in `setup.py` should be "**middle_abstraction**", the directory that contains the python file.

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['middle_abstraction'],#python pkg name
    package_dir={'': 'scripts'},
    requires=['std_msgs', 'rospy', 'message_filters', 'gps_common', 'sensor_msgs']
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

then create a  ****init**.py** file in the directory **middle_abstraction**, and don't forget to uncomment the `catkin_python_setup()` statement in **CMakeLists.txt** file.

Then after `catkin_make`, you can import the file like this

**a.py**

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append("..")
 import middle_abstraction.function_unit
```

---

Originally posted by [Niranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25953/niranjan/) with karma: 51 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on 2016-03-31**:
Thanks a lot! It works well for me. :)